# High-range obstacle detection system

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, proximity

I am making a high-range and fast obstacle detection system.

The HC-04 is too slow for that, other sensors don't have the range, and Lidar is too costly.

Any idea how to make a long range (more than 10 m) high-speed obstacle detection system?

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/products/3316 isn't the range, but is probably a lot faster. I don't think there is a solution that fits all your requirements.

Comment: Thanx for the reply but the rank is too short .

Comment: Is the sensor to be put on a mobile device or could you use a light sensor and shine a laser into it from the other end and detect when the laser beam is broken?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use PIR Sensor which is Cost Effective and covers upto 10 Meters

Comment: Thanx for reply, but they doesn’t really detect the presence of an object, but rather the motion
Offers no distance sensing capabilities
Does not detect stationary objects